# about generic and list mthod Contains() in C #

Tags: c#

```
List<Employee> staff = new List<Employee>();
Employee newHire = new Employee("John Smith", "1101");
staff.Add(newHire);
if (staff.Contains(newHire))
    Console.WriteLine("Yes the list contains the item we just added\n\t{0}", newHire.ToString());

newHire = new Employee("John Smith", "1101");
if (staff.Contains(newHire))
    Console.WriteLine("The list also contains this Employee");
else
     Console.WriteLine("Nope, can't find John Smith");
```

the code is used to explain how `Contains()` use, but I am confused about the 
instance newHire. It seems that we create this instance twice, And I don't know what is the difference between them.
I am new to C#, and English is not my native language.

Comment: there seems to be missing some code on the `Console.WriteLine()` for the second part.

Comment: `newHire` is just a variable, it's like a slot where you can assign `Employee` references. You do that twice, so the second time you overwrite the first assignment. The first `Employee` is now just contained in the list but not anymore referenced in this variable. The second `Employee` is not in the list but referenced by this variable. Both are different reference so `Contains` will not find the first anymore with `Contains`. You have to override `Equals`.

Comment: "It seems that we create this instance twice" That is true. Anyway although the two instances have the same **properties** doesn´t (neccessariyl) mean they are equal instances. You could achieve that by overriding `Equals`, if you wanted so.

Comment: You're creating two difference instances or `newHire`, but they both have the same values. You really have to show us the definition of `newHire` if you want anymore detail than that.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - And `GetHashCode` - you must override that too. And the object needs to be read-only.

Comment: I think it is a stupid example. The Contains compares the reference and not the data. Meaning the second time with a new instance of Employee, it won't find it even when it contains (haha) the same data.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  Thank you so much.

Comment: @J.vanLangen in fact, it is  an example from book...though I think it is a bad example as well.

Comment: @SukiHao: then the book tried to give you an example for why even the "same" object cannot be found with `Contains` if the class doesn't override `Equals`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You are right..At least next time I can avoid the same mistake I will make in my code. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is what happens:**

First you create an empty list and an object of type `Employee`

```
List<Employee> staff = new List<Employee>();
Employee newHire = new Employee("John Smith", "1101");
```

**now in memory we have**

> newHire --> points to address 0x00000001 // example of an address for the variable content

Then we put it in the list

```
staff.Add(newHire);
```

**memory**

> newHire --> points to address 0x00000001
>
> staff(0) --> points to address 0x00000001

The following code works, because the two adresses are the same

```
if (staff.Contains(newHire))
    Console.WriteLine("Yes the list contains the item we just added\n\t{0}", newHire.ToString());
```

Now the little trick

```
newHire = new Employee("John Smith", "1101");
```

This creates a **new object** of type Employee, with exacly the same info as the first object. **But it is a new one**

**so now in memory we have**

> newHire --> points to address 0x00000004 // A new address has been assigned to the new object
>
> staff(0) --> points to address 0x00000001

The following means "*Does staff contains an object stored at address 0x00000004 ?*"

```
if (staff.Contains(newHire))
    Console.WriteLine("The list also contains this Employee");
else
     Console.WriteLine("Nope, can't find John Smith");
```

And of course, the answer is NO, the list still keeps a reference to the object at 0x00000001

Comment: Your explanation is very clear and easily understood, thank you so much!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the feedback. If this answered your question, you can mark it as accepted, see good practices here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Override the `Equals` method which is used to compare `Employe` objects

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Employee(string name, string id)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Employee item = obj as Employee;
        if (item == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return this.ID == item.ID && this.Name == item.Name;
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FfoOHn

Comment: This is a follow up, on how to fix that example.

Answer (score 1):

newHire is a variable, a place to put things. This empty space is created when you define it:

```
Employee newHire
```

You create an Employee object with the 'new' keyword

```
new Employee("John Smith", "1101");
```

So this line does three things, it creates the Employee, defines a variable to hold it, and assigns the Employee to the variable.

```
Employee newHire = new Employee("John Smith", "1101");
```

Then a few lines later another Employee object (with the same data) is created and placed in the same varable.

```
newHire = new Employee("John Smith", "1101");
```

Comment: It's confusing that you've split the assignment into two lines, but you describe it as if you kept them together.

Answer (score 0):

newHire is just an object variable.

The first time it references the Employee John Smith. Then you add that to the list.

Then you assign Employee John Smith again as a **new object**.
As soon as you do this, the reference to the first object is lost.

Now the first employee object is inside the List. The second employee is not inside the staff list, but it is referenced by the same newHire variable

Comment: "Now the first employee object is inside the List." - that's confusing. It sounds like you're saying that by creating a second instance the first instance is put into the list.